# Apache Pig filtering out carriage returns

Tags: apache-pig

I'm fairly new with apache pig and trying to work with some fixed width text. In pig, I'm reading every line in as a chararray (I know I can use fixedwidthloader, but am not in this instance). One of the fields I'm working with is an email field and one entry has a carriage return that generates extra lines of output in the finished data dump (I show 12 rows instead of the 9 I'm expecting). I know which entry has the error but I'm unable to filter it out using pig.

Thus far I've tried to use pig's REPLACE to replace on \r or \uFFFD and even tried a python UDF which works on the command line but not when I run it as a UDF through PIG. Anyone have any suggestions? Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: JasonS , It would be helpful if you share sample input / Ouput of your scenario.

Comment: I've actually managed to solve this myself. It was much more simple than I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

My original edit with a solution turned out to only work part of the time. This time I had to clean the data before I ran it through pig. On the raw data file I did a `perl -i -pe 's/\r//g' filename` to remove the rogue carriage return.